# Increase frequency calls of touchesMoved

Tags: iphone, frequency, touchesmoved, touchesbegan

Is there a way to increase the frequency calls of touchesMoved than the default?  I need more calls of it to draw a smooth circle.  It gets called not too frequent by default and so I get an edgy circle.  Is there a way to tweek the frequency of touchesMoved calls?

Thanks

Comment: Why not interpolate between the given points using a spline or similar curve?

Comment: Can you please point me to some sample code for this?  I think this is what I need.

Comment: yes, this is what I need!  I did some googling.  But can't find sample code, would appreciate it if you point me to one, preferably for the iPhone sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

[UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html)

It comes with code examples, etc.

Comment: iPhoneOS doesn't have NSBezierPath. (It has UIBezierPath but only since 3.2)

Comment: This will work for me, I am doing development for the iPad.  Thanks