# Drawing on touch event

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm making a drawing tool with UIView's touch events.

The problem is

touchesMoved event doesn't occur when trying to move very closely
right after touch began.

so it's very **difficult to draw 2~3 pixels line**.

[image]
See it's just one pixel.

But in **iOS Simulator** it works fine.

[image]

I thought it's device's problem
But in **SketchBookX**(popular drawing app), works fine, too.

[image]

I'm not using UIScrollView or UIGuestureRocognizer.

Please help me to solve this problem.

- I took some screenshots AND 'newbies are not allowed to post images..' X(

Comment: post screen shots in some online site and share the link if its that important for your question

Comment: @Rohit OK, I added screenshots :)

Comment: Good Work! Quite an explanatory question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh FINALLY I found my fault!

[image]

If touch moves very short after 'touchesBegan', doesn't fire 'touchesMoved'.

But when 'touchesEnd' it gives moved point X(

It's little odd but finally i've done with it :)

Comment: can you told me how can i draw in touch event ? i read that to draw you should use drawrec function ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that on simulator input device is a mouse, where point of 'touch' is stricltly defined. Touchscreen works a bit different - 2-3px can be filtered as a noise.

People usually interpolate 'missing' pixels using UIBezierPath: see [Increase frequency calls of touchesMoved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702305)

Comment: I'm already using interpolation for very fast touch movement. But it can't solve my problem. Without any touchesMoved event, it's just nothing different with a pixel :(